# Login and Logout session with nodejs and html

Tags: html, node.js, session

I want to develop a login and logout session using nodejs server and html as frontend.I followed this tutorial https://codeforgeek.com/2014/09/manage-session-using-node-js-express-4/
My code is below
server.js

```
var express     =   require('express');  
var session     =   require('express-session');  
var bodyParser      =   require('body-parser');  
var app         =   express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

app.use(session({secret: 'ssshhhhh',saveUninitialized: true,resave: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());      
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

var sess;

app.get('/',function(req,res){  
    sess=req.session;  
    if(sess.email)  
    {  
        res.redirect('/admin');  
    }  
    else{  
    res.render('index.html');   
    }  
});

app.post('/login',function(req,res){  
    sess=req.session;     
    sess.email=req.body.email;  
    res.end('done');  
});

app.get('/admin',function(req,res){  
    sess=req.session;  
    if(sess.email)      
    {   
        //res.render('lg.html');  
        res.write('<h1>Hello '+sess.email+'</h1><br>');  
        res.end('<a href='+'/logout'+'>Logout</a>');  
    }  
    else  
    {  
        res.write('<h1>Please login first.</h1>');    
        res.end('<a href='+'/'+'>Login</a>');    
    }    

});  

app.get('/logout',function(req,res){    
    req.session.destroy(function(err){  
        if(err){  
            console.log(err);  
        }  
        else  
        {  
            res.redirect('/');  
        }  
    });  

});  
app.listen(3000,function(){  
    console.log("App Started on PORT 3000");  
})
```

The code is working well,it is logging in and logout properly but my problem is when i login if iam redirecting the admin page to my html page by placing a logout button iam not able to logout from there.Please Help me out.

Comment: May I see the index.html file?

Comment: Thank you for responding.I fixed this issue but now iam having another problem,when once a user logout the session he should not be able to perform any operations.The session should become disable.If any idea regarding this help me out.

Comment: does req.session.destroy() will help in making the session disable and not performing any other operation.?

Comment: You should put the answer of how you fix it, it will help others who have same question